# how do I save the result of loop for in a matrix?

Tags: matlab

I need to save  results of a for loop in a matrix where its size is 4*1?

My function:

```
function test()
for j=2:2:8
    h= 3*j
end
end
```

results:

```
h=6
h=12
h=18
h=24
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't need a loop for that, just do `h=3*(2:2:8).'`.

Comment: @Dev-iL, I posted a simple example from my work, so i need that structure,  Thank you any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via loop, and than you should first create the matrix:

```
function test()
n = 2:2:8;
h = zeros(length(n),1)
counter = 1;
for j = n
    h(counter) = 3*j
    counter = counter+1;
end
end
```

But that is the **long and non-efficient** way, instead you should use [vectorization](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html):

```
n = 2:2:8;
h = n.'*3
```

or just: `h = (2:2:8).'.*3;`

that's it.

Comment: Also take the transpose to match what the OP needs. i.e. 4x1 size output!!

Comment: Thank's for that comment, added it.

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Thank you very much for your help,  that example is just a somplification of the real function that I have. If I put the real function, no one does understand what really I want to do. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user6594048 I didn't give this answer! EBH did! 